# SlidingPanelLayout not work well from right to left in android

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-studio, android-sliding

I am creating **SlidingPanelLayout** from right to left for the `filter` purpose.The panel work fine it come out from right side and does animation but when Animation is stop it directly go to left side full but I want the ratio is 70% means `right side panel came out 70% of the total screen` and when click again it goes to hind and full Activity is display.

When first time Animation is stop the side panel goes to left side in the screenshot .But I want it right side.

**ScreenShot :**

[image]

but i want to display it write side and when click again it will go right side and hide again.

**activity_inventory.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e6e6e6"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    tools:context="com.example.softeng.jogi.InventoryActivity">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/backLayout"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/filter"/>

    <com.rey.material.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_bt_float_wave_color"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        style="@style/LightFABWaveColor"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**filter.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/filter_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0072BA"
        android:visibility="invisible">

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**filterAnimation.java**

```
public class FilterAnimation implements Animation.AnimationListener
{
    Context context;

    RelativeLayout filterLayout, otherLayout;

    private Animation filterSlideIn, filterSlideOut, otherSlideIn, otherSlideOut;

    private static int otherLayoutWidth, otherLayoutHeight;

    private boolean isOtherSlideOut = false;

    private int deviceWidth;

    private int margin;

    public FilterAnimation(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels; // as my animation is x-axis related so i gets the device width and will use that width,so that this sliding menu will work fine in all screen resolutions
    }

    public void initializeFilterAnimations(RelativeLayout filterLayout)
    {
        this.filterLayout = filterLayout;

        filterSlideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.filter_slide_in);

        filterSlideOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.filter_slide_out);

    }

    public void initializeOtherAnimations(RelativeLayout otherLayout)
    {
        this.otherLayout = otherLayout;

        otherLayoutWidth = otherLayout.getWidth();

        otherLayoutHeight = otherLayout.getHeight();


        otherSlideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.other_slide_in);
        otherSlideIn.setAnimationListener(this);

        otherSlideOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.other_slide_out);
        otherSlideOut.setAnimationListener(this);
    }

    public void toggleSliding()
    {
        if(isOtherSlideOut) //check if findLayout is already slided out so get so animate it back to initial position
        {

            filterLayout.startAnimation(filterSlideOut);

            filterLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            otherLayout.startAnimation(otherSlideIn);

        }
        else //slide findLayout Out and filterLayout In
        {
            otherLayout.startAnimation(otherSlideOut);

            filterLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            filterLayout.startAnimation(filterSlideIn);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
    {
        if(isOtherSlideOut) //Now here we will actually move our view to the new position,because animations just move the pixels not the view
        {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(otherLayoutWidth, otherLayoutHeight);

            otherLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

            isOtherSlideOut = false;
        }
        else
        {
            margin = (deviceWidth * 70) / 100; //here im coverting device percentage width into pixels, in my other_slide_in.xml or other_slide_out.xml you can see that i have set the android:toXDelta="80%",so it means the layout will move to 80% of the device screen,to work across all screens i have converted percentage width into pixels and then used it



            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(otherLayoutWidth, otherLayoutHeight);

            params.leftMargin = margin;

            params.rightMargin = -margin; //same margin from right side (negavite) so that our layout won't get shrink


            otherLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

            isOtherSlideOut = true;

            dimOtherLayout();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
    {

    }

    private void dimOtherLayout()
    {
        AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.5f);

        alphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

        otherLayout.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
    }

}
```

**InventoryActivity.java**

```
public class InventoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    RelativeLayout filterLayout, findLayout;

    FilterAnimation filterAnimation;
    FloatingActionButton bffilter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory);

        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        filterLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.filter_layout);

        findLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.backLayout);

        bffilter = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.button_bt_float_wave_color);
        bffilter.setOnClickListener(this);

        filterAnimation = new FilterAnimation(this);

        initializeAnimations();


    }

    private void initializeAnimations(){

        final ViewTreeObserver filterObserver = filterLayout.getViewTreeObserver();

        filterObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                filterLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

                int deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

                int filterLayoutWidth = (deviceWidth * 70) / 100;

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(filterLayoutWidth, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                filterLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

                filterAnimation.initializeFilterAnimations(filterLayout);
            }
        });


        final ViewTreeObserver findObserver = findLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        findObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                findLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                filterAnimation.initializeOtherAnimations(findLayout);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_inventory, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            this.finish();
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id){
            case R.id.button_bt_float_wave_color:
                filterAnimation.toggleSliding();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**filter_slide_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="130%"
        android:toXDelta="30%"
        android:duration="1000" />

</set>
```

**filter_slide_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="30%"
        android:toXDelta="130%"
        android:duration="1000"/>

</set>
```

**other_slide_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-70%"
        android:toXDelta="30%"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fillEnabled="true"/>

</set>
```

**other_slide_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="30%"
        android:toXDelta="-70%"
        android:duration="1000"/>

</set>
```

**My Question :** How I want to set right side panel to display and when click again it goes away. simply I my this code I want to remove the panel goes to full left see in the screenshot. the other part working fine.

**ScreenShot :**

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Doesn't the DrawerLayout do this already? This seems like a lot of code for a sliding panel

Comment: @cricket_007 I have already `DrawerLayout` in the `MainActivity` this is for the `filteration` purpose and in the `screenshot` is display not well I want it right side.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by filteration, but the XML you posted for filter.xml looks a lot like the other XML file you added

Comment: @cricket_007 i update it sorry i attach the wrong layout. `filteration` means filter the listview data.

Comment: Why are you not using _NavigationDrawerView_ or _DrawerLayout_ for that?

Comment: The majority of the code you've posted seems to be related to a sliding panel, not about filtering a ListView. Which, there seems to be a blog post on...  http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/11/android-recyclerview-filter-animation.html?m=1

Comment: @PiyushGupta Sorry But I am not this creating for Drawer I want it for `filter` and in the screenshot it display `left side` but I want it `right side`.

Comment: @cricket_007 I know the `filter` code is not there but First I simply want to create then I added it. because it the `layout is not work well then what is benefit for `filter``.

Comment: @cricket_007 you post the link is not work for me because I am `filter` listview data using `Web Api` query so this is not work for me.

Comment: A DrawerLayout can *contain* the ListView that you want to filter. That is why we are asking why you are not using it

Comment: @cricket_007 but my `SidePanel` doesn't contain `Listview` that's why I am creating this. `SidePanel` contain `3 Spinner` and `2 Button`.

Comment: Then I'm really confused with what you are trying to accomplish. Sorry... I understand you may want to fix your code here, but it's really easy to make a DrawerLayout on the left or right side of the screen and change how far it extends...

Comment: @cricket_007 I Understand what you are say but my problem is different so I am creating the `SildingpanelLayout`.

Comment: Okay, so I only see RelativeLayout in your XML, and not [`SlidingPaneLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html)

Comment: @cricket_007 I update my question I want that type right side panel in this `slider` are there you can see.

Comment: Thanks, but screenshots don't help address your problem. Providing a [mcve] does, and as I stated before, you seem to be recreating either the SlidingPaneLayout, DrawerLayout, or NavigationView that already exist.

Comment: @cricket_007 forget about data inside `rightSidePanel` just give me the reference to create panel only.

Comment: Like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059416/using-slidingpanelayout-from-the-right-hand-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the Solution. I am Creating the new Project.

**Sliding.java**

```
public class Sliding extends LinearLayout
{
    private Paint innerPaint, borderPaint ;
    public Sliding(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public Sliding(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }
    private void init() {
        innerPaint = new Paint();
        innerPaint.setARGB(0, 255, 255, 255); //gray
        innerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        borderPaint = new Paint();
        borderPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
        borderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    }
    public void setInnerPaint(Paint innerPaint) {
        this.innerPaint = innerPaint;
    }
    public void setBorderPaint(Paint borderPaint) {
        this.borderPaint = borderPaint;
    }
    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        RectF drawRect = new RectF();
        drawRect.set(0,0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
        canvas.drawRoundRect(drawRect, 5, 5, innerPaint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(drawRect, 5, 5, borderPaint);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

**Sliding2Activity.java**

```
public class Sliding2Activity extends Activity {

    CheckBox c1,c2,c3;
    int key=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sliding2);

        final Sliding popup = (Sliding) findViewById(R.id.sliding1);
        popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        final FloatingActionButton btn=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.show1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (key == 0) {
                    key = 1;
                    popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else if (key == 1) {
                    key = 0;
                    popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sliding2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_sliding2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.rey.material.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/show1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        style="@style/LightFABWaveColor"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

   <com.example.softeng.panel.Sliding
        android:id="@+id/sliding1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0072BA"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="1px">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Option1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Option2"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Option3"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </com.example.softeng.panel.Sliding>



</LinearLayout>
```

**ScreenShot :**

Normal screen when Activity is running.

[image]

When Click on **FloatinActionButton**. The layout is change.

[image]

When you click again the output is screen one.

Comment: Looks good to me. As long as you're happy with it and know how to maintain it, that's all that really matters here. You're welcome